# How to implement the Singleton in Objective-C and make sure the user never creates more objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I know that we can implement the Singleton pattern in Objective-C like this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static PPSettings *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

However, how do I make sure users would never be able to create more objects like this:

```
PPSettings *settingsObj1 = [[PPSettings alloc] init];
PPSettings *settingsObj2 = [[PPSettings alloc] init];
```

?

In other words, how we can achieve the same idea as Private Constructors in Java or C#?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.

Also, is it correct like:

```
instance = [[self alloc] init];
```

or better like this:

```
instance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
```

Comment: Peter Hosey has a great blog article about this: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-06-17/doing-it-wrong but the link is dead at the moment.

Comment: Thank you! Is it going to be live anytime in the future?

Comment: Looks like he's aware of it, but it's on a back burner: https://twitter.com/pgor/status/486942681839710208

Comment: The Wayback Machine has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20130925121124/http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-06-17/doing-it-wrong

Comment: Note that the user is still able to create instances using the runtime (objc), or reflection (java, C#).

Comment: For one you can code `init` to error out, and use `initForMySingleton` internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can disallow init in your header by using the `__attribute__` compiler directive:

```
- (instancetype) init __attribute__((unavailable("init not available, all access should be handled through the [YourClass sharedInstance] singleton")));
```

Comment: Will this prevent calling `-init` on `self` in the `dispatch_once` block?

Comment: Don't forget about `+new`.

Comment: @Riley Nope, the dispatch_once works as intended. Trying to init the class from "anywhere" else though, and the compiler will raise an error.

Comment: @nickfalk Is this because, within the `.m`, the compiler can "see" the method already? i.e., it doesn't "need" the declaration in the header? Or is that a simplistic or wrong view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+ (id) allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone` to make sure `alloc init` would never be able to create more objects.

```
static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (SingletonClass *) sharedInstance {

    if(!sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        });
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id) allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There have been many true singleton patterns (rather than the shared instance that is common used and mis-called a singleton), with ARC the following will work:

```
- (instancetype) init
{
   static Singleton *instance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

   dispatch_once(&onceToken,
                ^{
                   self = [super init];
                   if (self)
                   {
                      // any one-time init code
                   }

                   // save for next time
                   instance = self;
                });

   return instance;
}
```

Now you can:

```
[Singleton new]
```

or

```
[[Singleton alloc] init]
```

and you will only ever get the same instance. There will be a redundant `alloc` for each instance after the first which ARC will immediately clean up.

HTH

**Addendum**

Re: @HotLicks's first comment: If the cost of the `alloc` calls are too high you can just combine this with a `singletonInstance` method following the question:

```
+ (instancetype)singletonInstance
{
    static Singleton *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Of course programmers who choose to do `[[Singleton alloc] init]` will pay the cost, and that could be avoid by implementing `allocWithZone:`, but whether that is worth it will depend on the application. What the above `init` does is ensure that only one instance is ever created, regardless of whether `singletonInstance` or `[[Singleton alloc] init]` is used, and does so simply.

Re: @HotLick's second comment: Fair enough, that was assumed to be part of the one-time init code but it was probably a bit too brief. Edited code to make it clear.

HTH

Comment: Except that that's quite inefficient since the system will alloc your object every time you do `[Singleton new]` (which can be quite often in some environments).

Comment: And the above code does not show the call to `[super init]`.

Comment: @HotLicks - see Addendum